# How do I remove bold from a UILabel text in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel control (title) in a UITableViewCell (cell) where I set the font to bold using the following

```
cell.title.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.textFontSize];
```

How do I change the font back to normal/regular weight?

Comment: You don't "remove boldness from font", you assign a new, non-bold font to UILabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `systemFontOfSize` method on UIFont.

```
cell.title.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.textFontSize];
```

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something?

```
cell.title.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.textFontSize];
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you indeed just reassign `font` to a non-bold version of the font. As an additional note, if you don't have `self.textFontSize` available anymore (or it may have changed), you could do:

```
cell.title.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:cell.title.font.pointSize];
```

If the system font was just an example (and it could be an arbitrary bold font), then you could try to get the `familyName` of the existing font and use that in hopes of constructing a new non-bold version.